# Why if(DEFINED <variable>) doesn't work in cmake?

Tags: cmake

According to CMake documentation on [if](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html) keyword:

> `if(DEFINED <variable>)`
>
> True if the given variable is defined. It does not matter if the variable is true or false just if it has been set. (Note macro arguments are not variables.)

I have this small CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(abc)
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG 1: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
if(DEFINED ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG 2: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
endif(DEFINED ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG 3: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
```

which gives the next output on `cmake path/to/CMakeLists.txt` invocation:

```
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG 1: -g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG 3: -g
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: current/dir
```

Where is the second line?

```
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG 2: -g
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `if(DEFINED <variable>)` not `if(DEFINED ${<variable>})`.  In other words, use the variable name directly, don't expand it in the `if` (unless it contains the name of another variable that is what you actually want to test).

Comment: I have following in a .cmake file

add_definitions(-DENABLE_TEST)

if(DEFINED ENABLE_TEST)
    message("ENABLE_TEST    defined")
else()
    message("ENABLE_TEST    NOT defined")
endif()

Why the above if is always coming as not defined.

Comment: @RKum because `add_definitions()` defines macros for targets, like `#define` for C, not for CMake code below. If you want to define a var for CMake code, call `set(ENABLE_TEST true)` or similar.

Comment: how do you test in cmake if a certain C macro is defined? Is that even possible?